# `defined?` and `unless` not working as expected

Tags: ruby, local-variables, postfix-notation

I was expecting the following snippet:

```
var = "Not Empty" unless defined? var
var # => nil
```

to return `"Not Empty"`, but I got `nil`. Any insight into why this is happening?

Answer (score 10):

This is one of the only moments in Ruby I would call actual WTFs.

You have to use

```
unless defined? var
  var = :value
end
```

With the postfix syntax, the interpreter will internally `nil`-ify the value so it can reason about the variable, thus making it defined before the check is done:

```
# Doesn't print anything
unless defined?(foo) and (p(foo) or true)
  foo = :value
end

# Prints nil
bar = :value unless defined?(bar) and (p(bar) or true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Local variables are defined (as `nil`) at the point they are parsed. Definition of `var2` precedes the condition. That makes `var2` defined even when if the assignment is not executed. Then, the condition evaluates that `var2` is defined, which retains the value `nil` for `var2`.