# unless defined? is not working in my code

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I was expecting the following snippet:

```
var2 = "Not Empty" unless defined? var2
```

to return "Not Empty", but I got nil. Any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: the one who have down voted it please explain why he did it.

Comment: that was me, and I'm no 'he'. There's no context to know what `var2` is (or isn't) before this line of code. Why do you expect it to return "Not Empty"?

Comment: The behavior @ShahrozShaikh is describing happens in any context where `var2` hasn't been previously defined. If you put the above code in a Ruby file by itself it does exactly what @ShahrozShaikh says it does. Take a look, it's puzzling: http://ideone.com/ihm2Pt

Comment: Interesting. It seems to be evident if the variable being set is the same as the variable being checked. If you're setting a different variable it works fine.

Comment: That doesn't follow at all, @mwp.

Comment: @Jordan: We are not getting along, are we? What I mean is: `foo = 'bar' unless defined? qux` sets `foo`, but `qux = 'bar' unless defined? qux` does not set `qux`.

Comment: On the contrary, the latter sets `qux` to `nil`. That's the puzzling part. And sorry if I've been brusque.

Comment: Ah, indeed it does. No worries, I'm sorry if I've been horribly wrong in eight or nine of my assertions in this thread! (Which I have.)

Comment: I don't see an open issue at ruby-lang.org for this finding. Who wants to open one? I'm happy to if there are no other takers. I'll reference this question in the report.

Comment: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11659

Comment: Apparently this question is a verbatim copy of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838805/defined-and-unless-not-working-as-expected) (it's been marked as a duplicate), which makes me wonder if OP is a legitimate user. Regardless, the answers there explain what's going on here, which jives with the comment on the bug you filed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defined?` method will return:

**nil** => expression not recognizable

The problem in the above snippet is the scope of the local variable. `Its end on the line where you using it`. To learn more about local variable, please check this: [local_variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/localvars.html)

```
pry(main)> p "local_var is not initialized" unless defined? local_var
=> "loca_var is not initialized"
```

but if you do this:

```
pry(main)> local_var = "initialized" unless defined? local_var
=> nil
```

local_var is still `nil` because its scoped end after that line, so whatever assigned were wasted.

**Solution:** I will suggest if you want this behaviour then use this one:

```
local_var ||= "initialized"
```

Comment: `unless` isn't a scope gate, and indeed if you write it out (as in my answer), the variable is available after the `end`. Additionally, if you do `other_local_var = "initialized" unless defined? local_var`, the variable `other_local_var` is subsequently available! It's only when you try to set the uninitialized variable being checked in a one liner.

Comment: @mwp I agreed about this line `other_local_var = "initialized" unless defined? `. In-line if the structure has the same behavior as a block. So for the sake example when you map the above code in to block structure: `unless defined? local_var
  local_var = "initialized"
end`. then you can clearly see that **local_var** scope/life_cycle is only in the block. outside that block the value that was assigned no more exist.

Comment: @KhAmmad: You are mistaken. A variable initialized in an `if`/`unless` block still exists after the block. Look: http://ideone.com/OpWtlQ

Comment: thank you jorden for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var2 = "Not Empty" if var2.nil?` if you're trying to figure out if a variable is `nil` or not. `defined?` is used much more rarely and for different purposes (see below).

```
irb(main):009:0> var2 = nil
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> var2 = "Not Empty" if var2.nil?
=> "Not Empty"
irb(main):011:0> var2
=> "Not Empty"
irb(main):012:0> var2 = 'foo'
=> "foo"
irb(main):013:0> var2 = "Not Empty" if var2.nil?
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> var2
=> "foo"
```

If you aren't sure whether or not a variable has even been *declared*, you *can* use the following syntax:

```
if defined?(var2).nil?
  var2 = "Not Empty"
end
```

(It doesn't work all on one line for some strange reason, as @Jordan has pointed out, but this works.)

**However**, the idiomatic Ruby way to do this, in general, is called a "nil guard" and looks like the following:

```
var2 ||= "Not Empty"
```

Comment: This also returns `nil` and does not clarify the OP's doubt

Comment: Ah, my expression was negated. Fixed now. But agreed that it doesn't clarify the doubt.

Comment: any other  solution ?

Comment: What's wrong with this one?

Comment: If `var2` is nil before this expression, `var2` will be "Not Empty" after this expression. Isn't that what you are trying to accomplish? Don't confuse the return value of the expression with the value stored (or not stored) to `var2`.

Comment: Down one, up two, is the answer, is not the answer, down one, down two. What the heck is going on here? If someone has a better answer, post it!

Comment: This is being downvoted because it doesn't answer the question. OP asked why the behavior exists (when `val2` hasn't previously been defined, *not* when `val2` has previously been set to `nil`). Your answer suggests using `nil?` instead and doesn't even attempt to explain the behavior OP is seeing.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan. I see what looks to me like a new Ruby programmer and thought to steer him or her away from the `defined?` operator, because it is not likely what he or she is looking for. But I could be mistaken and the OP was actually trying to communicate a well-researched bug in Ruby to the community. :-) I've updated my answer with more examples and better explanations.